# FileSystemWatcher OnChanged Isn't raised for files updated live

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, onchange, filesystemwatcher

My `FileSystemWatcher` works fine for other files in the set directory but for files that are updated roughly every second by another program, the `OnChanged` event is only raised if I click a `button` on the GUI. I've made no link between the `buttton` and the `FileSystemWatcher`.

I'm trying to solve this by implementing a timer to call the OnChanged event.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(Page p in pages)
    {
     p.HandleFileChanged(sender, (FileSystemEventArgs)e);
    }
}
```

but I can't cast `EventArgs` to `FileSystemEventArgs` (worth a try!)

my `Page` class implements a `FileSystemWatcher` to watch a specific file.

I want to call the HandleFileChaned method, it's header is like this:

```
public void HandleFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
```

Comment: What's the question? Is it why the `FSW` doesn't work or how to handle both within the same event handler?

Comment: How about posting the code regarding your FSW, what you're doing may work but its a hack.

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why you don't add another layer like:

```
public void HandleFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    HandleFileChange(<path and file>);
}

public void timer1_Tick(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleFileChange(<path and file>);
}

private void HandleFileChange(string pathAndFile)
{
    // Do what you have to do
}
```

Comment: do you mean timer1_tick not button1_click?

Comment: Yes, of course. I just read he had a button and didn't actually see it was a timer event :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own FileSystemEventArgs?

```
var args = new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.All, "MyDir", "MyFile");
p.HandleFileChanged(sender, args);
```

Comment: now my program is a right mess! multiple methods are being called simultaneously from different threads :(

Comment: Are you implying that this is caused by the above code? I recommend fixing the FileSystemWatcher. I've used it before and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Your code works fine, thanks. It does what it is supposed to. But it's caused other problems.

Comment: What timer are you using and what UI Framework? Timers run in a different Thread. If your using WPF have a look at Dispatchertimer,